# create a stub bigquery table

Tags: java, testing, google-bigquery

For an integration test, I want to create a bigquery [Table](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/1.88.0/com/google/cloud/bigquery/Table.html) object that I will return from a test stub. I don't want to connect to a bigquery server and it's okay for this object to be mostly non functional/empty.

(This is an integration test so I don't want to use mocking)

Comment: Have you tried looking at how BigQuery itself does integration tests without needing a server? If not, create a Wrapper object that acts as a fake/stub

Answer (score 0):

Integration tests in Google Cloud validate interaction between parts of your code, and typically take a moderate amount of time to complete. For example, in Cloud Functions, integration tests can be used to test a function's usage of other Google Cloud services such as Datastore or Cloud Vision.

You can see more documentation about [integration tests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-basics#integration_tests) in Google Cloud.

There are already some libraries taking care of integration testing with datastores including BigQuery/NoSQL/SQL.

They would provide an easy solution for the cases described above and full support for SQL, dynamic macro/predicate.

- [Dsunit](https://github.com/viant/dsunit) (go-lang)
- [JDsunit](https://github.com/viant/jdsunit) (java)
- [Endly](https://github.com/viant/endly/)(language agnostic)

You can see more documentation about [integration tests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-basics#integration_tests) in Google Cloud.